# This is the answer of "Not getting result or intent data into onActivityResultMethod() in Fragment"

Tags: android, oop, android-fragments, fragment

If you are using onAcitvityResult() in parent acitivity of fragment than whatever you call or send any intent from fragment you will get the result into parent activity onAcitvityResult() method.
you need to handle it accordingly with activities and fragments.

My problem was i was not able to pick image in fragment using ImagePicker library or even without library and after spending 16-17 hours I solved it by removing onAcitvityResult() from parent activity because i was not using it anywhere.

PS: Sorry for bad english.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode : Int, resultCode : Int, data : Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_UPDATE_CODE) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be an answer, not a question.  Please post answers as answers, not questions.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is, after getting result from the Library you will get the callback first into the Parent Activity **onActivityResult()** method.

Now, in this **onActivityResult()** method you will have to decide basis of the **request code** that you have passed in **startActivityForResult()** method.

As we have the instance of the Fragment in our Parent Activity, so now, we can easily pass the callbacks into fragment using these instances.

Comment: Yes, I know the approach how to handle it, the problem is I was not aware of some other developer added it in parent activity which is unused. but thanks for your explanation.